# Can I share my iMac's internet connection via ethernet

Tags: imac, internet-sharing, ethernet

My iMac connects to the internet (and my local network) via WiFi. Is it possible for me to connect another device via ethernet cable to my iMac to access the internet from that device?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You sure can! Open System Preferences, then go to Sharing and select Internet Sharing. Change "Share your connection from:" to Wi-Fi, and then in the box below it select Ethernet.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that is the wrong way around. The OP has a WiFi and wants to share it on Ethernet!

Comment: @Buscar웃 I was lazy with the screenshot, but the instructions are correct.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answers but I can only mark one as the answer. @Patience gets it as its the earlier answer.

Answer (score 8):

Sharing your source Internet using WiFi to your Ethernet output.

[image: Sharing]